# How to print a colored text on white background with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Can I print a colored foreground on white background text with printext in OpenCV.

I tried with:

```
putText(frame, "Male", centerPrint,FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8,cvScalar(255, 0, 0), 1, CV_AA);
```

But it prints a blue text on transparent background.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

colors are bgr, not rgb ( so red is (0,0,255)). and you can't change the background.( unless you draw a filled rect with bg color there before)